# string input from textbox if/else

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-3.5

I am trying to use the input from a textbox as a string. The issue is that I need
it to only use it if the box is populated. My goal is to allow a user to input a username in the box, if the box is empty I would like it to still use my global static string if possible.
If any better ideas I am up for them

My program uses the USERNAME variable to get the username but I would like the option for the user to be able to enter username in box if they need.

```
string username = (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME"));
```

thankyou

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

//My original strings, This is what i need to fix

       static string config = File.ReadAllText("config.ini");
       static string username = (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME"));
       static string Backups = config + @"\" + username + @"\" + "Backups" + @"\";
       static string items;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

// How would i re purpose the string depending on the if?
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(toolStripTextBox1.Text))
            {
                toolStripTextBox1.Text = username;
                MessageBox.Show(username);

            }
            else
            {
                string username = (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME"));

            }
```

Comment: Why doesn't this work? Looks good to me....

Comment: u r doing exactly the same rite??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `toolStripTextBox1` is not empty, you are putting the value from the `username` string inside `toolStripTextBox1` .. ? 
Seems to me like the value coming out of the IF and Else both will be the same, being the username value taken from your config file.

So i'm not sure if i understand your question correctly, but I would guess you want something like this:

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(toolStripTextBox1.Text))
    {
      username = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
     MessageBox.Show(username); // will be the username the user enters in the textbox
     }
      else
    {
      MessageBox.Show(username); // will be the username taken from your config file
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct here is your problem.

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(toolStripTextBox1.Text))
            {
                toolStripTextBox1.Text = username;
```

It should be

```
string username = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
```